# Differentiating input from 2 separate keyboards

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

All,

Apologies in advance if this is an ill-informed question with lack of detailed examples of what I have tried to do so far - all the material I am finding on this topic seems to be out of scope of what I'm trying to do, or its just going right over my head (Learning resources on this are welcome!!).

What I am essentially trying to do is build a small program that will differentiate the input device used to create a user input on my Lenovo Win10 Machine that can run in the background and trigger scripts when certain conditions are met. In my case the input devices are a generic wireless/USB keyboard, and a USB Barcode scanner that acts as a HID Keyboard (The Barcode Scanners plugs directly into the machine, not via a keyboard).

The reason I need to differentiate the input is for example, if I have a script run every time an asterisk is printed from a scanned barcode I want the user to still be able to type an asterisk from the keyboard without triggering the script - Im restricted to using Code 128 barcodes so I also cant bypass this issue by adding characters to the barcodes to trigger the scripts that are not present on the keyboard.

In pseudo-code its essentially

```
start:
if inputdevice == keyboard 1
    then
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myBatchFileName);
    else
        goto start;
```

Initially I tried to do this in VB, using some code I had previously used to listen to a COM Port to record output from an arduino -

```
Dim barcodescanner As SerialPort   
barcodescanner = New SerialPort()

barcodescanner.PortName = "COMx"   
barcodescanner.BaudRate = 9600      
barcodescanner.Parity   = Parity.None     
barcodescanner.DataBits = 8             
barcodescanner.StopBits = StopBits.One  
Dim barcode As String          

barcodescanner.Open()                    
barcode = barcodescanner.ReadLine()  
barcodescanner.Close()
```

-however for reasons beyond me I cannot successfully use a virtual COM port for the scanner and record data this way, I also tried to create a virtual COM port using drivers from http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm but this was to no avail.

From some investigation I found some C# Classes, namely; InputEventArgs, InputDevice, RoutedEventArgs, that seem as if they could be used to resolve a device ID from an Input/Event that may allow be to harness some information I could use to flesh out and build the pseudo IF THEN ELSE loop above - but im struggling to use the classes and actually build any working code.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this?

In a perfect world if I could create a virtual COM port for the barcode scanner and listen to it using VB that would be ideal - but if not could anyone suggest a method of doing this in C# or point me to another method?

Comment: [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484332/determine-which-mouse-was-clicked-multiple-mice-devices-in-net) about multiple mice - perhaps some of the same methods can be applied to keyboards also.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, Windows automatically converts all keyboards into one input. This means that it would be impossible to get different inputs without altering windows or using a different operating system.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I didn't see this! Thanks, I'll have a dig around and see what I can use from that!

Comment: @DamienW I feared that was the case, afaik a CPU break is issued on keyboard/mouse input also which in my mind would make sniffing packets sent via USB and triggering a reaction based on that difficult also.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a keyboard-emulating scanner and a keyboard work the same way and Windows does not allow you to find out which device actually sent the keystroke.

One way would be (if possible for your scanner):

1. Configure the scanner to work as COM port emulation (not possible with all scanners, only industrial ones support this normally)
2. Install the manufacturer's virtual COM port driver if necessary

Then you can actually open a COM port and communicate with the scanner as desired - you then, however, need to put the scanned strings into text fields yourself if required.

Second possible solution (if available for your device):

1. Configure the scanner to transmit a certain prefix or suffix along with the barcode content (most scanners can be configured to send a barcode identifier before the content, which is highly unlikely to be typed by the user)
2. Also configure the scanner to send CRLF or CR as last character
3. When you receive CRLF or CR, check whether the input starts with that prefix/ends with that suffix
4. If it does, remove the prefix/suffix from the text box and react to the "*" as desired.

Comment: Yeah i have done the second suggestion before, if you set stx and etx as the prefix and suffice, you can happily listen for input from the scanner in the background, and display it anywhere you like and have little chance of having it confused with regular keyboard input

Comment: The COM port method would be ideal - however its seeming unlikely to work at this point - I'll keep playing with it, in the meantime your second suggestion is probably going to be the most realistic solution at this time - thanks!

Comment: @MarkusLewshinka Keep in mind that the scanner has to support the virtual COM port mode to work with virtual COM port driver. You can not simply install any virtual COM port software and make it work with the scanner and not all scanners support virtual COM port mode.